# How to print highest score from an external text file

Tags: python, csv

Help! I'm a starter coder and I am trying to build a top trumps game. I have created an external CSV file that stores the scores of the game. I am trying to get the game to print the highest score recorded but I am running in to a lot of errors. SOMEONE PLEASE HELP :(. I've been working on this for days now and the code keeps breaking more and more every time i try to fix it.

```
import random
import requests
import csv


def random_person():
    person_number = random.randint(1, 82)
    url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/{}/'.format(person_number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    person = response.json()
    return {
        'name': person['name'],
        'height': person['height'],
        'mass': person['mass'],
        'birth year': person['birth_year'],
    }


def run():
    highest_score = 0
    with open('score.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

        spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in spreadsheet:

            intscore = int(row['score'])

            if intscore > highest_score:
                highest_score = intscore

    print('The highest score to beat is', highest_score)
    game = input('Do you think you can beat it? y/n')
    if game == 'y':
        print('Good Luck')
    else:
        print('You got this')
    print('Hello stranger, Welcome to StarWars Top Trump!')
    player_name = input('What is your name?')
    lives_remaining = 1
    score = 0
    while lives_remaining > 0:
        my_person = random_person()
        print(player_name, ', you were given', my_person['name'])

        while True:
            stat_choice = input('Which stat do you want to use? ( height, mass, birth year)')
            if stat_choice.lower() not in ('height', 'mass', 'birth year'):
                print('Not an appropriate answer. Try again.')
            else:
                break

        opponent_person = random_person()
        print('The opponent chose', opponent_person['name'])
        my_stat = my_person[stat_choice]
        opponent_stat = opponent_person[stat_choice]

        if my_stat > opponent_stat:
            print(player_name, 'You Win! ')
            score = score + 1
            print(player_name, 'You have ', lives_remaining, 'lives remaining!')
            print('Your score is', score)
        elif my_stat == opponent_stat:
            print('Its A Draw!')
            print(player_name, 'You have', lives_remaining, 'lives remaining!')
            print('Your score is', score)
        elif my_stat < opponent_stat:
            lives_remaining = lives_remaining - 1
            print(player_name,  'You have,', lives_remaining, 'lives remaining!')
            print('Your score is', score)

        field_names = ['player_name', 'score']
        with open("score.csv", "w") as csv_file:
            spreadsheet = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
            spreadsheet.writeheader()

        data = [{"player_name": player_name, 'score': score}]
        with open("score.csv", "w") as csv_file:
            spreadsheet = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
            spreadsheet.writeheader()


        with open("score.csv", "a") as csv_file:
            spreadsheet = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
            spreadsheet.writerows(data)
        with open('score.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
            print('open file for reading')
            spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in spreadsheet:
            print(row)
            intscore = int(row['score'])
            print('SCORE: ', intscore)
        if intscore > highest_score:
            highest_score = intscore
            print(highest_score)


run()
```

This is one of the errors I get when I run the code

```
 line 26, in run
    intscore = int(row['score'])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'score'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEQgp.png)

Comment: Can you include a sample of what the spreadsheet looks like?

Comment: The PROBLEM here is that your CSV file contains a header row (or perhaps several).  You can always say `if row['score'] == 'score':` / `continue`

Comment: I've added a screen shot of what the spreadsheet looks like

Comment: Tim that was not helpful :(

Comment: Yes, it absolutely was.  You are using "append" to write to the CSV file.  Each `DictWriter` is going to write another new header row.  Did you look at the file?

Comment: Tim it wasn't ;(. show me ;(

Comment: Your last `for` loop needs to be indented so it is inside the `with`.  With that fix, I can't get your code to fail.  You always overwrite the CSV each time, so you don't retain any past information.

Comment: Timothy, I don't want it to overwrite the CSV each time. I want it to keep the score so I keep record of the highest and then print it

Comment: Well, then, that's your first bug.  You open the file for writing, then write the header (which erases the file), then you do that AGAIN, then you append your new data.  I'll suggest a better way to do that below.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) . I'll be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to manage the score database.  There's a "reader" that translates from CSV and returns a dictionary, and a "writer" that accepts a dictionary and writes it to file.  This is called "serialization" and "deserialization".

```
import random
import requests
import csv

def readscores(filename):
    scores = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
            scores[row['player_name']] = int(row['score'])
    return scores

def writescores(scores, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(['player_name','score'])
        writer.writerows( scores.items() )


def random_person():
    person_number = random.randint(1, 82)
    url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/{}/'.format(person_number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    person = response.json()
    return {
        'name': person['name'],
        'height': person['height'],
        'mass': person['mass'],
        'birth year': person['birth_year'],
    }


def run():
    scores = readscores('score.csv')
    highest_score = max(scores.values())

    print('The highest score to beat is', highest_score)
#    game = input('Do you think you can beat it? y/n')
#    if game == 'y':
#        print('Good Luck????')
#    else:
#        print('You got this????')
    print('Hello stranger, Welcome to StarWars Top Trump!')
    player_name = input('What is your name?')
    lives_remaining = 1
    score = 0
    while lives_remaining > 0:
        my_person = random_person()
        print(player_name, ', you were given', my_person['name'])

        while True:
            stat_choice = input('Which stat do you want to use? ( height, mass, birth year)')
            if stat_choice.lower() not in ('height', 'mass', 'birth year'):
                print('Not an appropriate answer. Try again.')
            else:
                break

        opponent_person = random_person()
        print('The opponent chose', opponent_person['name'])
        my_stat = my_person[stat_choice]
        opponent_stat = opponent_person[stat_choice]

        if my_stat > opponent_stat:
            print(player_name, 'You Win! ????')
            score = score + 1
        elif my_stat == opponent_stat:
            print('Its A Draw!')
        elif my_stat < opponent_stat:
            lives_remaining = lives_remaining - 1

        print(player_name,  'You have,', lives_remaining, 'lives remaining!')
        print('Your score is', score)

        scores[player_name] = score
        writescores( scores, 'score.csv' )

        print('SCORE: ', score)
        if score > highest_score:
            highest_score = score
            print(highest_score)

run()
```

This script works when starting with this data.  Note that it doesn't work if "score.csv" is missing; that's code you'd need to add.  It's not hard to handle.

```
c:\tmp>type score.csv
player_name,score
Tim,1
Joe,1
Bill,0
```

Comment: oh Timothy, :(. You had me excited. Then I ran the code and I was depressed all over again. i get three errors 1. line 81, in <module>
    run() 2. line 33, in run
    scores = readscores('score.csv') 3. line 9, in readscores
    scores[row['player_name']] = int(row['score'])
KeyError: 'score'

Comment: Maybe coding is not for me and I should just quit ;(

Comment: I think that's because you were inconsistent about capitalization.  Your example file has "Score" capitalized.  Try changing the header row to `player_name,score`, exactly.  I ran this code before posting it.  I know it works.

Comment: The header row IS player_name,score exactly, and I've made everything consistent. Ran the code and I still get errors. Thought I made a mistake elsewhere so I copied and pasted your code but still errors. I think I'm the problem. It's okay Timmy, you tried. I give up.

Comment: Tim...Timmy...Timothy... Have you abandoned me? Just because I gave up doesn't mean you should too

Comment: Yes, actually, it does.  And remember that the goal of this web site is to create a respected encyclopedia of technical questions and answers.  The powers that be don't appreciate the cutesy responses.

Comment: oops - sorry Tim. I apologise. Anyways, it works so thanks for all the help